# How to restart a coroutine

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I want to run my code multiple times without using the Update() method, now, I could use a coroutine or an Invoke(), but since the Invoke() is not very performance friendly as a coroutine, my best option is to use a coroutine instead.

Now, my problem is, when my coroutine is completed and I want to restart it, how exactly should I do it?

Here is what I've done, but it doesn't work:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DoSomething());
}

private IEnumerator DoSomething()
{
    //Does something
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    //Does another thing
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    StartCoroutine(DoSomething());
}
```

Comment: I believe your return statement is returning the coroutine.
Try removing the return and just use a yield new

Comment: @Natalo77 Your believe is wrong. `yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);` [is the correct way to do a 20 second pause in a coroutine method](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). For more information about what happens here syntactically, check out [the article about the yield keyword in the C# language](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put an infinite loop in your coroutine.

```
private IEnumerator DoSomething()
{
    while(true) {
        //Does something
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
        //Does another thing
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
    }
}
```

You can still stop that loop by destroying the game object which started the coroutine or with [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html). If you have some exit condition for the loop which you want to check within the coroutine, you can either turn the infinite while-loop into a while-loop with a condition or break out of the loop [with the `break;` keyword](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before, and it didn't work, then I tried it again, right now and it works...so weird. Thanks again.

Comment: Note also that you can use “yield break;” to quit early. It’s the equivalent of “return;” within a coroutine.